# Estou começando a programar em React Native. Qual o melhor software para emular o android? e para editar as linhas de programação

Tags: android, react-native

Como dito acima, estou começando a programar apps para Mobile, e estou com bastante duvidas, uma delas e pelo fato de ter assistido a um tutorial de como instalar o React e etc... No qual o autor fala que e necessário o Android Studio, porém ele nem utiliza o mesmo para emular o Sistema operacional... Me ajude por favor!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/fun-zone/), ele é o mais leve de todos e esse hiperlink leva ao download da versão free(Funzone).

Também pode optar pela ADV(Android Virtual Device) fornecida pelo [android studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/?hl=pt-br), porém esta consome muitos recursos da máquina.

Você pode escolher a IDE [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) como edição. Possui "auto complete" para muitas linguagens de programação e fmw, inclusive alguns destes que você utilizará para criar um app RN, tais como: Json, TypeScript, JavaScript puro, ES15+, Redux e por aí vai...

Se seu professor disse que não precisa do **Android Studio** para emular o sistema, ele quis dizer que **não precisa em partes**. O **android studio** através das suas **SDK's** vão criar uma imagem de um **SO android** com as especificações que você escolheu tão quanto as **configurações de hardware**, e depois só ficará responsável por **startar a AVD** e **pode fechá-lo tranquilamente**... Se você **configurar certo** seu ambiente de desenvolvimento **bastará executar**

> react-native run-android

e ele **startará** a AVD **automaticamente**